# После выполнения функции 1, бот останавливается и не вызывает функцию 2

Tags: python, бот, sqlite3, telegram

При запуске локально на PyCharm, бот добавляет данные в БД SQLite3 и модерирует комментарии к публикации. Но, после загрузки на VPS, останавливается после выполнения первой функции и не вызывает вторую.

В чем причина?

Вот код бота:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def mess_data(message: types.Message):
    if not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id):
        db.add_user(message.from_user.id, message.from_user.first_name)

@dp.message_handler()
async def mess_handler(message: types.Message):
    text = message.text.lower()
   
    if str(message.from_user.id) != cfg.ADMIN_ID:
        for word in cfg.WORDS:
            if word in text:
                await message.delete()
```

Comment: Начать стоит с логичного вопроса — что такое `./`? Если вы указали относительный путь, значит он ищется относительно текущего рабочего каталога — какой текущий рабочий каталог у запущенного бота?

Comment: Без символов тоже не работает) Логи выдает без ошибок, если же закомментировать строки с кодом управления БД, бот работает отлично. Если раскомментировать, бот останавливается и ошибок в логах тоже нет

Comment: Без символов всё то же самое, `database.db` это путь относительно текущего рабочего каталога, а какой текущий рабочий каталог-то?

Comment: /root/moderator

Comment: Выяснил, что дело в вызове функции: останавливается после выполнения первой функции и не вызывает вторую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась тем, что в конце первой функции добавил

```
await mess_handler(message)
```

т.е. вызов второй функции.